# Check if a transaction to database is finished in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have a `@Component` class with `@Transactional` annotation.
In `onApplicationEvent` method I save same data in db and after that I call `System.exit(0)`.

But data isn't saved and I want to check when the data is saved.

I use `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()` but always is true.

How I can check safe if a transaction is finished?

Comment: What library are you using for your Data Layer?

Comment: PostgreSql with Hibernate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolve the problem with another service class where I save data in DB and this service is `@Transactional`. And in `@Component` class I called the service method.

Answer (score 0):

1)
Not sure it is latest, but you need a transaction interceptor, like that:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html

and listen to afterTransactionCompletion(...)

2)
you can simply wrap the DB calling method by try-catch and if calling method exited without exception - transaction is done. (in case you do not catch exceptions inside).

wrap your java code that calls the DB save like that:

```
try{
    saveData()...

    //transaction was OK here, I can System.exit
    System.exit();
}catch(Exception e){
     //transaction failed, I need so something
     soSomething();
}
```

Comment: But I want to do this just for one job. Not for all project. So, I think the interceptor isn't the best solution. I don't understaning the `try-catch` solution.

Comment: replied in my answer

Comment: I tried it but doesn't work System.exit() is called before insert in database.

Comment: I think you have a very fundamental problem: your @Component is not in transnational context. Even, if put an annotation on it. Start to check, if all that works WITHOUT System.exit.  You may find that it does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of ApplicationEvent do you listen to? If it is a custom event produced by your own code (via `ApplicationEventPublisher`) then you can put `org.springframework.transaction.event.TransactionalEventListener` annotation on your event-handling method and it will be invoked after transaction is committed. (if event was published of course)